# Simple vlookup function returning value from line below expected line

Tags: google-sheets, syntax, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup

I have created a simple Google Spreadsheet with

```
|   | A   | B |
|---|-----|---|
| 1 | CAD | 4 |
| 2 | BTC | 3 |
| 3 | USD | 2 |
```

I am expecting `=vlookup("CAD",A1:B3,2)` to return "4", but it returns "3". My question is: **what is the logic behind this?**

- `=vlookup("CAD",A1:B3,2,FALSE)` returns 4 as expected in Google Sheets.
- `=vlookup("CAD",A1:B3,2)` returns 4 in LibreOffice.

See enclosed images.

[image: vlookup in google sheets vs in libreoffice]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, nothing much here to say. doing vlookup like this:

```
=VLOOKUP("CAD", A1:B3, 2)
```

and not including the 4th vlookup parameter, the formula will default the 4th parameter as `TRUE` or `1` so it's basically same as:

```
=VLOOKUP("CAD", A1:B3, 2, 1)
```

or

```
=VLOOKUP("CAD", A1:B3, 2, TRUE)
```

and by having the 4th parameter as `1` or `TRUE` we are telling the vlookup to run the **approximate** mode not the **exact** mode. the exact mode would be any of these:

```
=VLOOKUP("CAD", A1:B3, 2, )
```

---

```
=VLOOKUP("CAD", A1:B3, 2, 0)
```

---

```
=VLOOKUP("CAD", A1:B3, 2, FALSE)
```

mostly you will need the exact mode, unless you need to vlookup number between two other numbers like **https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/123730/186471**

and to explain why you get value `3` for `BTC` when you seek the `CAD` is because **B** is before **C** in the alphabet

Comment: Thanks. It's still counterintuitive to me that looking up "CAD" in approximate mode would return a result for "BTC", and not "CAD", because "CAD" is closer to "CAD" than "BTC" is. However, I now understand to never use approximate mode if we are not searching for numbers.